# Tuleap artifact document exporter

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, export, documents, tuleap

Is it possible, or is there any plug-in available, to generate pdf or word documents from existing artifacts with tuleap.

I am looking for something like this availble for jira:
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.midori.jira.plugin.pdfview
http://www.midori-global.com/downloads/jpdf/jira-software-requirement-specification.pdf

My goal is to generate a project documentation for sign-off documents for my customers. I am wondering if this would be possible with tuleap.

I am not using tuleap right now, but rather evaluating ALM-software for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

No, to my knowledge there is no built-in way to do such a thing. But, you could easily try to use the REST API to query the trackers and extract artifacts; this way you could then build your own documents.

Or you can also contribute such a feature, it would be a pleasure :)